# Whats the appropriate place to define a lookup table?

Tags: c

While wrting an application , I wrote a single lookup table (an integer array)

While performing lookup, I have written an api which takes the input and returns an output, and the lookup table is defined in that api.?

Should I initialize that lookup array in global scope as const array (places it in data segment)

What is the advantage of initializing it in an api / defining it in data segment ?

PS: the lookup table is less than size 50.

Comment: Thanks all for the various approaches, but my question assuming I define the const lookup[] globally it'd be in data segment of elf, would it really help in execution time? So, I want to know if at all placing variables in data segment of elf file helpful in any scenario ? sorry for the confusion ...

Answer (score 3):

The principle of encapsulation says that every "class" (or object, or struct, ..) must disclose the least amount on information about their inner structure, so it depends on your design.

It's generally a good rule to declare the lookup table as const array : the compiler will optimize the array (for example by putting it in low-speed write time and good access-time memory banks).

If you need to access the lookup table from code located in several files, declare your table in a separate file `xxxLookupTable.c`, write a wrapper around it (like `xxxLookupTableManager` ) in `xxxLookupTable.h` and link the header wherever the lookup is needed

Answer (score 3):

My typical approach would be:

```
int lookup_stuff(int stuff)
{
   static const int table_of_stuff[] = { 1, 2, 7, 8, 14, 20, 24, 29, ... }; 

   assert(stuff < sizeof(table_of_stuff)/sizeof(table_of_stuff[0])); 
   /* if stuff comes from an external source, such as a user modifiable text file, 
      the assert should be converted to an "if" so that it's present in all 
      versions of the code, not just debug builds */
   return table_of_stuff[stuff]; 
}
```

Comment: You could further use `size_t` or some other unsigned type as parameter.

Comment: Typically, I would use `uint32_t` or `unsigned int` - on a 64-bit machine, `size_t` is (normally) 64 bits, which MAY cause slower execution than 32-bit values. But I was trying to stick with the original poster's type of `int`.

Comment: I implemented in the exact same fashion, but I got a comment during peer-review of "might consider" defining it as an global const array (it'd be in data segment) ... is it something useful mentioning about data segment?

Comment: If you have `static` in the declaration, it will make no difference at all - it is global in all aspects except the fact that the variable name isn't visible to other functions. Which I think is a benefit unless you need the table in more than one function.

Answer (score 1):

The most import imperative of all software design is to manage complexity, if you define a lookup table as a global structure you may later create unnecessary dependencies between modules that access the lookup table. Therefore having an API is a better approach IMHO (assuming there are no other factors performance). With an API you can for instance change the size of the lookup table without being afraid of that some module assumes a certain size and also do error handling.

Answer (score 0):

An option that avoids global is to declare it as a static inside the function that provides the look up functionality
.